# Cannot decrypt ciphertext from php encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I can't  decrypt this cipher using crypto-js.

plain text key: 'abcdabcdabcdabcd'

iv: `'0000000000000000'`

secret message: `'5555555555555555'`

ciphertext: `'jIwKE2X1N/1aiZfWoaY+USXRnslF1tsXKVtUON8ucn0='`

My crypto-js code looks like this:

```
var iv  = '0000000000000000';
var aesKey = 'abcdabcdabcdabcd';
var ciphertext = 'jIwKE2X1N/1aiZfWoaY+USXRnslF1tsXKVtUON8ucn0=';
var decryption = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, aesKey, {iv: iv});
console.log( decryption.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

After runing this code the console.log is empty, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I',m not sure but it looks like this
  $iv = str_repeat("\0", openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-128-CBC'));
So i think it's propably '0000000000000000'

Comment: Done, also i attached a link with decryption object
https://ibb.co/cg8c8v

Comment: You very likely need to apply `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse` to your `iv` in JavaScript (and possibly your key as well?) Your IV in PHP is a series of null bytes, but in JS it's a series of `48`-value bytes (the ASCII value of the character `0`). `Hex.parse` will read the input as series of 2-character bytes. Alternatively, use actual null bytes instead of a series of zeros, `"\0\0\0\0..."`

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. By accepting a answer you are indicating to future readers that it is a correct answer.

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, needed for formatting

Given:

```
keyString:           "abcdabcdabcdabcd"
ivString:            "0000000000000000"
secretMessageString: "5555555555555555"
ciphertextBase64:    "jIwKE2X1N/1aiZfWoaY+USXRnslF1tsXKVtUON8ucn0="
```

Displayed as hex:

```
keyHex:                  61626364616263646162636461626364
ivHex:                   30303030303030303030303030303030
secretMessageHex:        35353535353535353535353535353535
secretMessageHexPadded:  3535353535353535353535353535353510101010101010101010101010101010
ciphertextHex:           8c8c0a1365f537fd5a8997d6a1a63e5125d19ec945d6db17295b5438df2e727d
```

Putting these values into an online [AES Calculator <kbd>Encrypt</kbd>](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=61626364616263646162636461626364&iv=30303030303030303030303030303030&input=3535353535353535353535353535353510101010101010101010101010101010&mode=cbc&action=Encrypt&output=9494DA8CD4DD92415C694BBC41EA45F8962F8D02505127FC2657461011085028):

```
ciphertextHexCalculated: 319C920C815076E0DD863FCB5AE8DDBD6D8065E9B4D285E06B0F58DD1F0EA3B7
```

Note that this is not the same as the question provided ciphertext.

There is something that is not correct with parameters, options or data.

**However** the decryption does work with an IV of 0x00 bytes:

```
keyString:           "abcdabcdabcdabcd"
ivHex: 00000000000000000000000000000000
secretMessageString: "5555555555555555"
```

[Online AES Calculator <kbd>Decrypt</kbd>](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=61626364616263646162636461626364&iv=00000000000000000000000000000000&input=3535353535353535353535353535353510101010101010101010101010101010&mode=cbc&action=Decrypt&output=319C920C815076E0DD863FCB5AE8DDBD6D8065E9B4D285E06B0F58DD1F0EA3B7)

Which is incorrect because the clear text is being used as the encrypted text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does it mean that i paste bad data? 
Sorry for my silly questions bu it's the first time i'm dealing with cryptography.